# On the Chinese translation of a quote by Richard Deacon

Tags: translation, culture, movies

According to my previous question on [Movies Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121479/102751), Richard Deacon (理查德·迪肯) says in the original English track of the movie "Richard Deacon - In Between"

> What's creative? Recognizing something that pops into your head as being interesting.

which is translated on the German track as

> Was ist kreativ? Etwas, was dir durch den Kopf schießt, als interessant erkennen.

There's no definite answer wether there are international releases of this movie and other language versions than German and English (cf. my questions on [Movies Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121501/102751) and on [Quora](https://de.quora.com/unanswered/What-are-the-international-releases-and-language-versions-of-the-documentary-Richard-Deacon-In-Between-which-appeared-first-in-Germany?ch=10&oid=175410123&share=bebfbdcf&srid=hVkRVV&target_type=question)), specifically if there's a Chinese release with potential Chinese subtitles, but the silence on the side of the answers suggest there are none.

Hence, I would like to ask you: How would you translate this quote into Chinese?

My preliminary thoughts on the translation - you can choose other more advanced wordings:

- The first question could be rendered: 什么是创意？
- Recognizing could become realize as 发现
- Head in this context is probably 大脑
- Idea is maybe 思想
- Interesting is maybe 有趣

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brain, as a collection of ideas floating around, can be called 脑海 -- 海 = sea which is a good metaphor.

Thus "pops into your head" can be translated into "闪现在脑海".

思想 is usually reserved for ideas that are deep and profound. Something that "pops" is probably not that serious. 想法 is sufficient. Likewise 发现 is probably too profound. Here "recognizing" is probably just realizing something is interesting and worth developing.

Hence: 什么是创意？就是意识到脑海里闪现的想法是有趣的。

Answer (score 1):

Subtitles can be terrible! All written by AI. I don't like "Etwas was ... " although it is not wrong.

Was ist "kreativ sein"?
What is "being creative"?
什么是"有创造力的"?

"Kreativ sein" ist wenn du etwas, das dir durch den Kopf schießt, als interessant erkennst.
"Being creative" is when you recognize that an idea which you have is interesting.
成为一个有创造力的人就是意识到你的一些主意很有趣.